# CSS animations not working properly on macOS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a flipbox with basic HTML and SCSS.
It's working as intended on Windows machines on every browser but I can't get it to work properly on Mac machines. It's not browser specific because it won't work properly on any browser on a Mac. The animation with the text is flickering and also the text disappears after the animation is done. I tried using different webkit solutions after Googling for a while, but none seem to fix my issue. I really hope someone here could help me out since I have no clue anymore on what is causing this issue. I do know that it has to do with the way it's getting rendered.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 d-flex team-card">
    <!-- card container -->
    <div class="extraSpacing">
      <!-- inner -->
      <div class="content front">
        <div class="name text-center mx-auto mt-auto">
          <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="function text-center mx-auto mt-auto">
          <p style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:12px;">Function</p>
        </div>
        <div class="social text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </div> <!-- /social -->
      </div> <!-- /content front -->
      <div class="back">
        <p>Back card content</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /inner -->
  </div> <!-- /card container -->
</div> <!-- /row -->
```

```
#teamWrapper {
margin: 75px 0;
.team-card:hover .extraSpacing {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.team-card {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    transition: all .6s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s linear;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;

    .extraSpacing {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: 365px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        transition: transform 0.8s;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .social {
        margin-top: 15px;
        i {
            color: white;
            margin: 0 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            transition: .2s all;
            -webkit-transition: .2s all;
            &:hover {
                color: red;
                -webkit-transition: .2s all;
                transition: .2s all;
            }
        }
    }
    .front {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .back {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        background: white;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;

        p {
            color: black;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    }
    p {
        color: white;  
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

The URL is: https://ikycreative.ikydev.nl/over-ons/ and the problem is with the team cards at the bottom of the page. It should flip over with a white background and black text, which it does on Windows (Chrome, Firefox) but not on Mac (Safari, Chrome, Firefox). It flickers a lot on Mac.

Many many thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated since I am clueless.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zLcjy4em/1/

Comment: did you try * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

Comment: Please create a [MRE] _within your question_. We don't need to see your PHP as it is likely irrelevant. Just enough HTML and CSS to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem only with Safari. Chrome on a Mac is working well

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLcjy4em/1/

Weird that it is working for you on Chrome MacOS. I've tried multiple different Macbooks on the office variating from 2011 tot 2018 models and on none of them it's working properly. In this Fiddle it is reproducing the exact same problem for me.